# How to get count of parse push notifications on Android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working on Parse notifications in Android; I want to get the total number of push notifications for my app to display as a badge on my app's launcher icon. I noticed that in iOS we can get badge number but in Android, I get badge = "Increment".

How can I  get count of push notifications on Android?